# 404 Not Found Error when trying to access localhost on local LAMP server

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, http-status-code-404, lamp

I'm running Ubuntu. My Apache2 default file looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /var/www/
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

I have this file called Index.php in /var/www/

```
<?
phpinfo();
?>
```

When I access http://localhost/ in my browser, I'm getting the 404 Not Found error:

The requested URL / was not found on this server.
Apache/2.2.16 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80

What am I doing wrong? This actually worked when I first setup LAMP but it's not working now.

Comment: @Codemwnci No offence, but how could he get the error message from Apache if it wasn't running?

Comment: Are you sure there aren't 2 apaches running at the same time? It could cause similar problems.

Comment: I've never done anything that would indicate two Apaches running at the same time. Like I said, this worked when I first set it up, then what happened was I changed the DocumentRoot to another location and changed it back, and then it started not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled. It seems like my upgrade to 10.10 has wiped the symlinks from that directory. Try symlinking default to /etc/apache2/sites-available/default

```
sudo ln -s /etc/apache2/sites-available/default /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default
```

Comment: and you restarted apache as well?

Comment: Okay, after I restarted Apache2 I get to the 'Index of /' page, where I can see the directory. How do I get it to once again default to the Index.php page in that directory like it used to?

Comment: easiest way, just rename Index.php to index.php

Comment: or, you can edit /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dir.conf, adding Index.php to DirectoryIndex

Comment: Thank you! Awesome job following up.

Answer (score 2):

Check out error log (tail /var/log/apache2/error.log) in order to find out exact path that Apache tries to find.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the PHP module installed and enabled? Because, normally, it would mention that in the server signature, but yours doesn't. That would also explain why the server doesn't recognize that `index.php` is what you mean by `/`.

Try

```
sudo a2enmod php5
```

Answer (score 0):

Exactly the same problem with me.

Following worked for me :

As **Andreas Jansson** mentioned, symlink default to:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/apache2/sites-available/default /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default
```

and restarted apache2:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

and then it works:

```
http://localhost/
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the url localhost/info.php.
File info.php must contain 
`<?php
phpinfo();
?>`