# I'm not able to access localhost on my linux m/c running Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu)

Tags: php, html, linux, apache2, lamp

Accessing http://localhost or http://127.0.0.1 gives me a 404 URL not found error. This is in spite of me having apache 2.2.14 running on my PC (the apache process is started). Any help in this regard will be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: check your error_log file to find out the cause of the problem

Comment: I think this link will be helpful to solve your issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060034/404-not-found-error-when-trying-to-access-localhost-on-local-lamp-server

Comment: Got my problem fixed. I had to remove a site from /etc/apache2/sites-enabled and had to be set to default file thereafter. Restarted Apache and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're getting a 404 not found it means that the server is running but can't find the document you're looking for.

If you look in your Apache config file you'll find a setting for "document root".  Place a file called "index.html" in that directory.

This usually defaults to /var/www on Ubuntu.

For more info you can check the [Ubuntu community site](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP)

Comment: The index.html file is present at /var/www . That doesn seem to be the problem.