# Why isn't apache finding my index.php?

Tags: php, apache

I have a vagrant box set up to forward the port of guest 80 to host of 8080, when I go to host 8080 I get 404 file not found. according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060034/404-not-found-error-when-trying-to-access-localhost-on-local-lamp-server) it seems to be a symlink issue, but my sym links are set up properly:

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled$ ls -l
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant 41 Apr  8 00:19 000-default.conf -> /etc/apache2/sites-available/default.conf
```

Or at least I am pretty sure thats proper. My `default.conf` looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

  DocumentRoot /var/www/dirty_bird

  # correct caching issue where edited images do not refresh http://www.mabishu.com/blog/2013/05/07/solving-caching-issues-with-vagrant-on-vboxsf/
  EnableSendfile off

  <Directory /var/www/dirty-bird>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
  </Directory>

  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/dirty-bird.error.log

  # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
  # alert, emerg.
  LogLevel warn

  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/dirty-bird.access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

When I do `vagrant up` and then visit `localhost::8080` I get: `404 File Not Found` I am sure this is something simple, but im not sure what. Google mostly tells me its a symlink issue, but unless my symlinks are wrong, it's not in this case. and apache is running.

Comment: But where's the vhost record for listening on port 8080

Comment: You should not need it (provide docs please) as the guest machines apache is running on 80 and I am forwarding that port to 8080

Comment: I think you have wrong understanding of ports and how apache works. I dont know what exactly you are forwarding to 8080, but if nobody listening on port 8080 it's like forwarding to into nowhere. And how symlinks related to apache? Now, apache is listening to port 80 - so it newer will work on 8080 if you dont change it.

Comment: Anyway, does command "a2ensite dirty_bird" works? Read apache's logs file.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Are open in your firewall the port 8080?
Look in your VirtualHost the port 80, change to 8080.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
```

Ty

Comment: This seems wrong. The guest machine forwards port 80 to the host machine, which is port 8080, apache is running in the guest machine on port 80. Also downvoted